# pandas insert new first row and calculate timestamp based on minimum date

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i am looking for a more elegant solution than my code. i have a given df which look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

sdate = date(2021,1,31)
edate = date(2021,8,30)
date_range = pd.date_range(sdate,edate-timedelta(days=1),freq='m')
df_test = pd.DataFrame({ 'Datum': date_range})
```

i take this df and have to insert a new first row with the minimum date

```
data_perf_indexed_vv = df_test.copy()
minimum_date = df_test['Datum'].min()
data_perf_indexed_vv = data_perf_indexed_vv.reset_index()
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(data_perf_indexed_vv.columns)],
                   columns=data_perf_indexed_vv.columns)
data_perf_indexed_vv = df1.append(data_perf_indexed_vv, ignore_index=True)
data_perf_indexed_vv['Datum'].iloc[0] = minimum_date - DateOffset(months=1)
data_perf_indexed_vv.drop(['index'], axis=1)
```

may somebody have a shorter or more elegant solution. thanks

Comment: Discard the second block of code and add: `min_date  = pd_test['Datum'].min() - DateOffset(months = 1)`   `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Datum': min_date})` and then finaly use concat or append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing such big 2nd block of code just make use of:

```
df_test.loc[len(df_test)+1,'Datum']=(df_test['Datum'].min()-DateOffset(months=1))
```

Finally make use of `sort_values()` method:

```
df_test=df_test.sort_values(by='Datum',ignore_index=True)
```

Now if you print `df_test` you will get desired output:

```
#output

    Datum
0   2020-12-31
1   2021-01-31
2   2021-02-28
3   2021-03-31
4   2021-04-30
5   2021-05-31
6   2021-06-30
7   2021-07-31
```